# How to SAY after DAIL

Tags: twilio

I have an incoming call that triggers an outgoing call. When the outgoing call is answered, I want to SAY an announcement, ideally without the original caller hearing it.

I tried to respond with a TwiML to the callStatusCallback and I also tried nesting the SAY node within NUMBER. Both didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

What you're referring to here is commonly known as a [call whisper](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/call-whisper).

You can implement it by providing a [URL to the `<Number>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-url) in the [TwiML](http://twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/) you return that forwards the call. That URL should return some more TwiML, in this case [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) with the text you want to read out. Then when the call is forwarded, Twilio will make a webhook to that URL when the user answers and only connect the calls when the TwiML is complete.

Let me know if that helps at all.